# How can I make a class iterable in Java to use foreach loop

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, iterable

I try to create a manual LinkedList class and then I made a function to merge two LinkedList. I implement iterable for my LinkedList class in order to use foreach loop but something went wrong. I don't know how to override iterator() function to solve problem. this is my code:

*Node.java*

```
package app;
public class Node<R> {
    private R Data;
    private Node<R> nextNode;
    public final void setData(R data) {
        Data = data;
    }
    public R getData() {
        return Data;
    }
    public void setNextNode(Node<R> nextNode) {
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }
    public Node<R> getNextNode() {
        return nextNode;
    }
    public Node(R dR){
        this.setData(dR);
    }
}
```

*LinkedList.java*

```
package app;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class LinkedList<R> implements java.lang.Iterable<R>{
    private Node<R> headNode;
    public void addNode(Node<R> nR){
        if(headNode == null){
            headNode = nR;
        } else {
            nR.setNextNode(headNode);
            this.headNode = nR;
        }
    }
    public void addData(R dR){
        Node<R> nR = new Node<>(dR);
        addNode(nR);
    }
    public LinkedList(){
        headNode = null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<R> iterator() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

*App.java*

```
package app;
public class App {
    public static <R>LinkedList<R> unionLinkedList(LinkedList<R> list , LinkedList<R> list2){
        LinkedList<R> unionLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        for (R dR : list) {
            unionLinkedList.addData(dR);
        }
        for (R dR : list2) {
            unionLinkedList.addData(dR);
        }
        return unionLinkedList;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
        list.addData(3);
        list.addData(9);
        list.addData(8);
        list2.addData(11);
        list2.addData(5);
        list2.addData(7);
        LinkedList<Integer> u = unionLinkedList(list, list2);
    }
}
```

I know I have to change `return null;` in `iterator()` but I don't know what should replace it.

Comment: I believe you need to define a new class ListIterator<R>, which has methods "boolean hasNext()" and "R getNext()" methods, and then have your "iterator()" method return an instance of ListIterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I can do it with this modification:

```
@Override
public Iterator<R> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<R>(){
        Node<R> current = (Node<R>) headNode;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext(){
            return current != null;
        }

        @Override
        public R next(){
            if (hasNext()){
                R dR = current.getData();
                current = current.getNextNode();
                return dR;
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

in *LinkedList.java*

Answer (score 2):

You implement the `Iterable` interface.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

> public interface Iterable
>
> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the
> "for-each loop" statement.

At the very least you'll need to return an iterator.

> Iterator   iterator()
>
> Returns an iterator over elements of type T.

'null' (as in your code) is not an iterator.  You'll need to implement a class (can be nested, if you like) that knows how to iterate over your particular linked-list implementation.  Probably, all it needs is a 'next node to process' member; the next() and hasNext() methods can be implemented with just that.

Comment: due I'm not Java Programmer, I don't know how can I modify it. I'm a R-Programmer but now I need Java for this problem.

Comment: Then why the heck are you implementing a LinkedList when Java already provides one?  If this is a "learn Java" exercise, then what I wrote should be sufficient to code from; I'm not planning to write it. If this is not intended to teach some Java, then use java.util.LinkedList.

Comment: yes it's an exercise.